# Hide Admob APP ID From Sniffer/Modder/Hacker

Tags: admob, adsense, sniffer

**Hello,

Is there anyway to hide admob APP ID, So That it can't be revealed to the Sniffer/Hackers/Modders.
I recive Ads Unit and Admob APP ID Remotely from my APP Panel. How Can I not use App id in manifest/String.

Please Provide Your Valuable Suggestion.

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possibility of maliciously attacking via your AD-unit-ID is slim. However, someone could still use your APP-ID and AD-unit-ID to generate an invalid traffic which leads your AdMob account suspended.

According to [this document](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants), you may put these IDs in your **build.gradle** file and automatically switch your test-AD-IDs / real-AD-IDs by selecting different build types.

Here is my code in **app/build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_debug"
        resValue "string", "ad_banner_id",   "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"  // test unit id
        resValue "string", "ad_rewarded_id", "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917"  // test unit id
    }

    release {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_release"
        resValue "string", "ad_banner_id",   "ca-app-pub-***/***"  // real ad unit id
        resValue "string", "ad_rewarded_id", "ca-app-pub-***/***"  // real ad unit id
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
}
```